# Why is the Error Can not convert from ICollection<T> to List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, oop

```
    List<Question> withTags = 
Question.GetRecentQuestionsWithTags(StackExchangeSite.StackOverflow, "c#");
```

The above code have a compile error;

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'.

Though it works with .ToList() but why the error in first place?

```
List<t> implements from ICollection<T> and so does ICollection<Question>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a `ICollection` is not a necessarily a `List` but could be any other collection as well, like a `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 2):

Just because every `List` is an `ICollection`, it does not mean every `ICollection` is a `List`.

Just because every Doctor is a human being, that does not mean that every human being is a doctor.

Basic logic.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `ICollection` cannot be implicitly casted to `List`. It would though go the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Add ToList()

```
List<Question> withTags = 
Question.GetRecentQuestionsWithTags(StackExchangeSite.StackOverflow, "c#").ToList();
```

You can always convert a list to a collection (List class is an ancesotor), but it doesn't go the other way around.

Comment: In question already Mentioned that ToList() works , But Why the error